# Does the .Net Compact Edition 3.5 support the Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I know SQL CE supports it but my understanding is that .Net 3.5 CE might not.

I'm specifically wondering if we can use the Entity Framework in Windows Mobile 6.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't use the Entity Framework API from the .NET Compact Framework, there are no plans for this implementation by the product team.